# Find "fraction of bright pixels" in image (thresholding?)

Tags: image-processing, grayscale, threshold

I have a large number of grayscale images that show bright "fibers" on a darker background. I am trying to quantify the "amount" of fibers. Since they overlap almost everywhere it will be impossible to count the number of fibers, so instead I want to resort to simply calculating how large the area fraction of the white fibers is compared to the full image (e.g. this one is 55% white, another one with less fibers is only 43% white, etc). In other words, I want to quantify the density of the fibers in the image.

Example pictures:

High density: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14309718/f1.jpg

Lower density: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14309718/f2.jpg

I figured a simple (adaptive) threshold filter would do the job nicely by just converting the image to purely black/white and then counting the fraction of white pixels. However, my answer seems to depend almost completely and only on the threshold value that I choose. I did some quick experiments by taking a large number of different thresholds and found that in all pictures the fraction of white pixels is almost exactly a linear function of the threshold value. In other words - I can get any answer I want between roughly 10% and 90% depending on the threshold I choose.

This is obviously not a good approach because my results are extremely biased with how I choose the threshold and therefore completely useless. Furthermore I have about 100 of these images and I'm not looking forward to trying to choose the "correct" threshold for all of them manually.

How can I improve this method?

Answer (score 2):

As the images are complex and the outlines of the fibers are fuzzy, there is little hope of getting an "exact" measurement.

What matters then is to achieve repeatability, i.e. ensure that the same fiber density is always assigned the same measurement, even in varying lighting conditions if possible, and different densities are assigned different measurements.

This rules out human intervention in adjusting a threshold.

My best advice is to rely on Otsu thresholding, which is very good at finding meaningful background and foreground intensities and is fairly illumination-independent.

Enhancing the constrast before Otsu should be avoided because binarization commutes with contrast enhancement (so that there is no real benefit), but contrast enhancement can degrade the image by saturating at places.

Comment: Thanks. I think the fuzziness of the outlines is exactly the problem I'm having, because increasing the threshold seems to result simply in taking more of the fiber into account (e.g. more of the blurry edge is counted) so it makes sense that it is so dependent on the threshold. Is there nothing that tackles this problem specifically? The fuzziness should be very similar in all images so perhaps an algorithm that looks at the gradient from black to white and picks some intermediate value as the 'edge'? I've no idea how this could be achieved just brainstorming. I'll look into Otsu threshold.

Comment: @NickThissen: don't worry about the fuzzy edges, just use an empirical measurement. Repeatability is more important than any kind of "correcteness".

Answer (score 0):

Just echoing @YvesDaoust' thoughts really - and providing some concrete examples...

You can generate histograms of your images using ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows. I am just doing this at the command-line but it is powerful and easy to run some tests and see how Yves' suggestion works for you.

```
# Make histograms for both images
convert 1.jpg histogram:h1.png
convert 2.jpg histogram:h2.png
```

[image]

[image]

Yes, they are *fairly* bimodal - so Otsu thresholding should find a threshold that maximises the between-class variance. Use the script `otsuthresh` from Fred Weinhaus' website [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/otsuthresh/index.php)

```
./otsuthresh  1.jpg 1.gif
Thresholding Image At 44.7059%

./otsuthresh  2.jpg 2.gif
Thresholding Image At 42.7451%
```

[image]

[image]

Count percentage of white pixels in each image:

```
convert 1.gif -format "%[fx:int(mean*100)]" info:
50

convert 2.gif -format "%[fx:int(mean*100)]" info:
48
```

Not that brilliant a distinction! Mmmm... I tried adding in a median filter to reduce the noise, but that didn't help. Do you have your images available as PNG to avoid the nasty artefacts?